# How would a parent class call its own method within itself in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins

I am trying to create the concrete class `Val15` class with the Mixins, `MyCollection`, `Val5`, `Val10`. `Val15` is trying to inherit `values` from `MyCollection`. When `Val15` is instantiated, I am trying to call both `Val10`'s and `Val5`'s  `value` and add them to `Val15`, `values`.

However, it turns out that `Val15` will inherit only `Val10`'s value and all the classes will call `Val10`'s value. How exactly can you overturn this problem?

```
class MyCollection(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.values = []


class MyMessage(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def message(self):
        print('Hello World')


class Val10(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Call 10')
        self.values.append(self.value())

    def value(self):
        print('Value 10')
        return 10


class Val5(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Call 5')
        self.values.append(self.value())

    def value(self):
        print('Value 5')
        return 5


class Val15(Val10, Val5, MyMessage, MyCollection):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def my_sum(self):
        return sum(self.values)


val15 = Val15()
val15.my_sum()
val15.message()

# Result:
# Call 5
# Value 10
# Call 10
# Value 10
# Hello World
```

Comment: This is one of the few cases where leading double underscores would actually make sense, to avoid this kind of clash (see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables).

Comment: I tried doing that for both classes, and I still have the same problem.

Comment: The problem is `self` is always a `Val15`, so its own method is first in the MRO. Without being explicit (`self.values.append(Val10.value(self))` or invoking `super` in various places this is the behaviour you should expect.

Comment: I think you need to reconsider the structure of your classes. For instance, what should `val15.value()` print and what value should it return? Should it print both `5` and `10` or just `15`, or neither of those options?

Answer (score 1):

This is the interesting part:

```
class Val10(object):
    def value(self):
        return 10

class Val5(object):
    def value(self):
        return 5
```

To get the sum of parents' values, you have to call each of them:

```
class Val15(Val10, Val5):
    def value(self):
        return Val10.value(self) + Val5.value(self)
```

### Alternative solution

Another approach is to define that `value` always returns the sum of all inherited values, whatever they may be, without knowing which parent classes' `value` to call:

```
class Val10:
    def value(self):
        previous = getattr(super(), 'value', lambda: 0)()
        return previous + 10

class Val5:
    def value(self):
        previous = getattr(super(), 'value', lambda: 0)()
        return previous + 5

class Val15(Val10, Val5):
    def value(self):
        return getattr(super(), 'value', lambda: 0)()

Val15().value()  # 15
```

This solution does not make any assumptions about the way inheritance is going to be configured.

**Remarks:**

- The answer assumes that this is Python 3, because of the `super()` syntax
- `getattr(super(), 'value', lambda: 0)` returns the bound `value` method of the parent class, if such exists, or defaults to a function which returns 0.

Comment: I like your first solution. It;s cleaner